# Pairwise comparison - too many groups

Tags: multiple-comparisons, statistical-power, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, wilcoxon-signed-rank, bonferroni

I have 23 groups that I am comparing. I was just going to show the distribution of the groups with boxplots but a reviewer of my manuscript wants me to do group testing. The trouble is that pairwise comparisons for 23 groups results in 253 comparisons.

Using a technique to limit family-wise error rate, like Bonferroni, seems far too stringent in this situation, but even using a technique to limit false discovery rate, like Benjamini & Hochberg (1995), seems too stringent.

I am using Kruskal-Wallis and pairwise Wilcoxon given the distribution of my data.

Are there good ways to compare 23 groups?

Comment: You should **not** be using "pairwise Wilcoxon" (i.e. rank sum tests) following rejection of a Kruskal-Wallis test, because (1) the rank sum tests actually use different ranks than the Kruskal-Wallis used to reject its null, and (2) the pairwise rank sum tests do not use the pool variance estimate from the Kruskal-Wallis test, and implied by its null. You want to use Dunn's test (dunntest in Stata, dunn.test in R), or (more powerful) the Conover-Iman test (conovertest in Stata, conover.test in R). Also: Welcome to CV!

Comment: Also, you do not say what you mean by "too stringent"? While Dunn's Bonferroni adjustment does indeed hemorrhage statistical power with a large number of pairwise comparisons, the false discovery rate is very good at preserving rejection probabilities for a specified false discovery rate, even when the number of tests is very high.

Comment: When I say too stringent, I mean "hemorrhage[ing] statistical power" as you put it. Are the p-values for the comparisons really meaningful when you have reduced your statistical power so significantly?

Comment: I can only assume you do not understand how much more power to reject the Benjamini-Hochberg's FDR method has over the Bonferroni (or even Holm) methods.

Comment: You don't show data, so it's difficult to give specific advice. Are there particular pairs among the 23 that are of particular interest? What interesting claims you you want to make in your paper? It is hard to imagine your paper now ponders 253 comparisons. Is the omnibus hypothesis strongly rejected, or does the P-value barely sneak under 0.05? // It's your paper and you have a right to focus on & defend points you consider important. Maybe doing a few key comparisons will support your claims and satisfy reviewer.// Once it's clear what needs to be done,  we can try to find the best way.

Comment: This is my data: https://github.com/natearoe/myrepo/blob/master/group_testing.csv I am trying to compare the groups by their variable importance. The figure that goes along with it is this: https://github.com/natearoe/myrepo/blob/master/VarImpPlotNew.pdf //The reviewer wants me to show whether the groups are different. I personally felt that looking at the distributions themselves was insightful. @BruceET, I do like your idea of just comparing particular groups among the 23. That could be useful.